# HLS stream not playing with Videojs on Mobile Firefox

Tags: firefox, mobile, http-live-streaming, video.js

I have a problem playing HLS (m3u8).

I have a System with some Live streams. To play these streams I wrote a Webpage using Videojs.

This runs smoothly on Desktop with Chrome, Firefox and even Edge.
But with Mobile the Firefox wont play it anymore.

The Firefox Browser gets the playlist, shows the first frame and gets stuck. It then shows the following error:

> A network error caused the media download to fail partway.

the code Iam using looks like this

```html
<div>
    <video
        id="my-video"
        class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
        controls
        <?php if(isset($_GET["autoplay"])) echo "autoplay"; ?>
        preload="auto"
        width="1920"
        height="1080"
        poster="pic/Video_Hintergrund.png"
        data-setup='{"fluid": true}'
        onplay="onVideoStartPlaying();"
        onpause="onVideoStopPlaying();"
      >
        <source src="[...]/index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
          To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
          web browser that
          <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
            >supports HTML5 video</a
          >
        </p>
      </video>
    </div>
```

The Webpage and the Stream are located on the same Server.

Does anyone have some tips what I can try?

Comment: I have the same issue, as the stream works in firefox but not in chrome.